# How can i read the db in my android app which i've modified in my pc and copied back to my app's db folder

Tags: android

What I am trying to do is that I have a db which I've created in my app. I am copying that same db from my phone(My phone is rooted so it's easy for me to copy it and paste on my mac). On my Mac through SQLite Manager I'm inserting the data(Doing this because I have requirement where I need to import a csv file into the db) later I am copying back the same db file into my app database folder.

The problem is that my app is crashing whenever I try to insert or read the db file.

Here's my Manifest file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.uttara.dbpull">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Here's my DBhelper class.

```
    public class DHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "sampledata1";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME="sampledata1";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String NUMBER="NUMBER";
    private static final String NAME = "NAME";
    private static final String SURNAME = "SURNAME";
    private static final String MARKS = "MARKS";
    private static final String SQL_CREATE_TABLE_SAMPLE = "CREATE TABLE     sampledata1 (NUMBER INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, NAME TEXT, SURNAME TEXT, MARKS INTEGER)";

    public DHelper(Context applicationcontext ) {
    super(applicationcontext, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_TABLE_SAMPLE);

}

@Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sampledata1");
    onCreate(db);

}
    public boolean insertData(String name,String surname,String marks){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(NAME,name);
    contentValues.put(SURNAME,surname);
    contentValues.put(MARKS,marks);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
    if (result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;

}
    public Cursor getAllData(){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " +TABLE_NAME,null);
    return res;
}
}
```

My MainActivity.class

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
DHelper myDb;
EditText editname,editsurname,editmarks;
Button btnadd,btnview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myDb=new DHelper(this);
    editname= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_name);
    editsurname= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_surname);
    editmarks= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_marks);
    btnadd= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_add);
    btnview= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_view);
    viewAll();
    addData();

}
public void addData(){
    btnadd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          boolean isInserted=  myDb.insertData(editname.getText().toString(),editsurname.getText().toString(),editmarks.getText().toString());
            if (isInserted==true)
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Data inserted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            else
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Data not inserted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

}
public void viewAll(){
    btnview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           Cursor res= myDb.getAllData();
            if (res.getCount()==0){
                showMessage("Error","NO DATA FOUND");
                return;

            }

            StringBuffer buffer=new StringBuffer();
            while (res.moveToNext()){
                buffer.append("NUMBER :"+ res.getString(0)+"\n");
                buffer.append("NAME :"+ res.getString(1)+"\n");
                buffer.append("SURNAME :"+ res.getString(2)+"\n");
                buffer.append("MARKS :"+ res.getString(3)+"\n\n");

            }
            showMessage("Alert",buffer.toString());
        }
    });
}
public void showMessage(String title,String Message){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(Message);
    builder.show();
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
E/SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database '/data/user/0/com.uttara.dbpull/databases/sampledata1'.
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:237)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:221)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:468)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:190)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:182)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:876)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:856)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:754)
at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:579)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:269)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:223)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
at com.uttara.dbpull.DHelper.getAllData(DHelper.java:55)
at com.uttara.dbpull.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:50)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5226)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21266)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5845)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)

    --------- beginning of crash
    07-05 11:29:06.732 16734-16734/com.uttara.dbpull E/AndroidRuntime:         FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.uttara.dbpull, PID: 16734
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:237)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:221)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:468)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:190)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:182)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:856)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:754)
at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:579)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:269)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:223)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
at com.uttara.dbpull.DHelper.getAllData(DHelper.java:55)
at com.uttara.dbpull.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:50)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5226)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21266)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5845)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I will explain how to copy existing database schema in Android app and good practices to deal with `SQLite DB`, so that it will be helpful to others as well. This way is useful when you have static database schema.

Recommended way to use database object in Android application is, create it at application level and use it through out the application.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application{
    public DBHelper dbHelper;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());
            try {
                dbHelper.createDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

Don't forgot to mention your application name in AndroidManifest file in `application` tag.Suppose your application class name is MyApplication and it resides in com.app package then it should be :-

> android:name="com.app.MyApplication"

Below is DBHelper class which working as a bridge between our application and local database.

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Your database name";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static String DB_PATH = "";
    private SQLiteDatabase mDataBase;
    private final Context mContext;

/**
     * Called when the database is created for the first time. This is where the
     * creation of tables and the initial population of the tables should happen.
     *
     * @param db The database.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

/**
 * Called when the database needs to be upgraded. The implementation
 * should use this method to drop tables, add tables, or do anything else it
 * needs to upgrade to the new schema version.
 * <p/>
 * <p>
 * The SQLite ALTER TABLE documentation can be found
 * <a href="http://sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html">here</a>. If you add new columns
 * you can use ALTER TABLE to insert them into a live table. If you rename or remove columns
 * you can use ALTER TABLE to rename the old table, then create the new table and then
 * populate the new table with the contents of the old table.
 * </p><p>
 * This method executes within a transaction.  If an exception is thrown, all changes
 * will automatically be rolled back.
 * </p>
 *
 * @param db         The database.
 * @param oldVersion The old database version.
 * @param newVersion The new database version.
 */
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

 /**
     * Create a helper object to create, open, and/or manage a database.
     * This method always returns very quickly.  The database is not actually
     * created or opened until one of {@link #getWritableDatabase} or
     * {@link #getReadableDatabase} is called.
     *
     * @param context to use to open or create the database
     */
    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17){
            DB_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";
        }
        else
        {
            DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
        }
        this.mContext = context;
    }

/**
Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
     * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
     */
    public boolean checkDataBase(){

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try{
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }catch(SQLiteException e){

        //database does't exist yet.

    }

    if(checkDB != null){

        checkDB.close();

    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}
/**
 * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
 * */
public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if(dbExist){
        //do nothing - database already exist
    }else{
        //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
        //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
        this.getReadableDatabase();

        try {

            copyDataBase();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            throw new Error("Error copying database");

        }
    }

}
/**
 * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
 * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
 * This is done by transfering bytestream.
 * */
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME+".sqlite");

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;

    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    //Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
    //Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
    mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {

    if(mDataBase != null)
        mDataBase.close();

    super.close();
}
}
```

**Now this might be solution for your problem. You just need to open the database from your activity, do database operations and after done with it just close it. Below is code snippet :-**

```
MyApplication application = (MyApplication) getApplicationContext();
application.dbHelper.openDataBase();
boolean isInserted=application.dbHelper.insertData(editname.getText().toString(),editsurname.getText().toString(),editmarks.getText().toString());
application.dbHelper.close();
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Kindly mention the reason for downvote in commnets. It will helpful for me to update my answer.